# $(Ajax) triggering synchronously while made request to FLASK API which returns HTML String without Script tag

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

I need to made request to a Python Api (Flask) which return a HTML String **(pd.to_html(DataFrame)-Return DF to html )** which doesn't contain any  tag in it. Just String has HTML and CSS.

Issue: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check [http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."](http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.%22)

**Note:** I have checked all the threads regarding this in stack-overflow nothing worked for me.

I am posting my Ajax call below which is,

```
    function Ajaxify(filename,city){
  var PythonUrl='<?php echo ($url); ?>';
  var randomInt= Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000000000000) + 1);
  var user= sessionStorage.getItem("user");
  var rand= user+"_"+String(randomInt);
  var data_to_be_passed=city+"   "+rand;
  var parameters=$.param({path:'PythonCode',pythonfile:filename,data:data_to_be_passed});
  $.ajax({
      async: true,
      type: 'POST',
      url: PythonUrl,
      data: parameters,
      beforeSend: function()
      {
        $('#loader').css('display','block');
      },
      success: function(data)
      {
        $('#loader').css('display','none');
        $('body').html(data);
      },
      error: function(x, t, m) {
        if(t==="timeout") {
            alert("got timeout");
        } else {
            alert(t);
        }
    }
  });
}
```

Versions:

- Jquery=/*! jQuery v1.7.1 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */ (Unfortunately my org sticking to this version - Advise me if i upgrade this above 3.0 will work??)
- Chrome Version : Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I made Async:true as well just saw some threads where this solved issue. But not in my case.

I should return html string in JSON format? Say- {data:htmlString}

Please Advise me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: The warning you see (*"Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated"*) has nothing to do with the code you show. There must be a different Ajax request that triggers it. The jQuery version you use is unimportant, they all work the same for Ajax. The return format is up to you, but if your response data is HTML then wrapping *that* in JSON does not improve anything whatsoever.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks, there is no other ajax request present in my code. Ok if i use pure js xmlHttprequest will work for me?

Comment: There must be a different Ajax request in your code because this one is not triggering the warning. Usually the warning in the browser console links to the code that causes it.

Comment: @Tomalak Sorry About that , I checked the entire code there is no other ajax call other than i post above.So from your point the code throws warning on jquery doc.h.open(c.type,c.url,c.async);if(c.xhrFields)for(j in c.xhrFields)h[j]=c.xhrFields[j];c.mimeType&&h.overrideMimeType&&h.overrideMime

Comment: @Tomalak And Also if i remove the line $('body').html(data); it works fine. Can you please advise me?

Comment: could it be that the HTML you insert contains more Ajax requests?

Comment: @Tomalak No it has only html and css alone <table><\table> please advise me , i was also tried everything . No workaround also there.

Comment: @Tomalak ok i understood something actually the success(data) is gives back the same html file again instead the response.Why so?

Comment: Because your server code does the wrong thing?

Comment: @Tomalak you mean FlaskAPI not handling the request properly ?

Comment: I mean *something* is executing a synchronous Ajax request on your page and triggers the warning you see. It's not the code that you show here because this clearly is an asynchronous request. You have to track down the piece of code that is responsible, and I can't help you with that. I can only see the code you show and this code is not at fault. Open the developer tools, look at the network tab, reload the page and figure it out. :)